# Removing index from url in code igniter

Tags: codeigniter

So this question here may seem very simular to many that people have already have, but it is different.

What I want to do is have the index portion of the url removed.
Currently, I have an application that has a few pages (a home page, an about page, and a contact page.  They are all loaded through a controller I call Pages.

When I load this pages in, there is no problem.  They all load the way I want, which, on my local development they are as follows

localhost/codeigniter for the index of home page
localhost/codeigniter/about for the about page
and
localhost/codeigniter/contact for the contact page

Now, I creates a seperate controller to handle the contact page, which I called Contact.  There isn't anything in there except a reload of the contact page.  The code is as follows

```
$this->load->view('contact');
```

This is the exact code I use in the pages/contact controller.

However, what I am trying to do, is simple send flashdata from the Contact controller back to the contact page.  It all works fine; however, the url is this

localhost/codeigniter/contact/index

This only occurs when I use another controller to load in a view like this.

Is there any solution for this?  I mean, when calling the page from its main controller is works fine.  That is to say, that the url is this

localhost/codeigniter/contact.

So I don't think it is a rewrite rule through the htaccess or anything, or a routing problem.  But I could be wrong.

Currently, by .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

And my routes are this:

```
$route['contact'] = 'pages/contact';
$route['about'] = 'pages/about';
$route['/'] = 'pages/index';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

I tried to add in a route for the contact/index to route to contact, such as this:

```
$route['contact'] = 'contact/index';
```

but that didn't work.

It seems to me that this would not be an issue if controllers could talk to one another, however, I haven't found any information about this any where.

Does someone have a suggestion for me, as to have to fix this issue.  Thanks.

Comment: How do you take flash data?

Comment: Try some of these htaccess https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter and make sure you have placed the htaccess out side of the application folder.

Comment: Is the contact function still there in pages controller & from where you are trying to call the new contact controller ?

Comment: Can you please add some code snippet stating how you move from your old controller to the new one, when you say

except a reload of the contact page.

What does it really mean, there should be something that is reloading?